# Array Initialization: int versus other Objects

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm confused on whether I need to do array initialization...

For this code:

```
private int[][][] rPos = new int[SIZE][SIZE][2];
```

Can I start using the array right way, like the following line?

```
getLocationOnScreen(rPos[i][j]); // pass an array of two integers
```

And, for this code:

```
View[][] allViews = new View[SIZE][SIZE];
```

I then have to make another nested loop, and initialize every `View` by calling their constructors like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        allViews[i][j] = new View(ctor1, ctor2);
    }
}
```

My question is, why didn't I need to do this for an integer array? And also, what did my "new" keyword do, when I typed `View[][] allViews = new View[SIZE][SIZE];`?

Comment: With primitives, initial value is `0`, `0.0`, or `false`. For reference types, it is `null`. That's why you don't need to do this for an integer array (of one dimension). However, you still need to initialize the dimensions.

Comment: @Sotirios Oh yea, I remember that now! But on the second line, didn't I pass in "an array of two integers", and hence that's a reference, not a primitive type?

Comment: Yes, you have. If that array hasn't been initialized, you will get a `NullPointerException` trying to dereference it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why didn't I need to do this for an integer array?

Whenever you create an array, the array elements are assigned the default value for the component type of that array. For an `int`, the default value is `0`, so for an `int[]`, all the elements will be initialized to `0` by default.

With reference type, however, the default value is `null`. So, the issue with those arrays are that, you might get potential `NullPointerException`, when you try to access some property or method in those array elements. Basically, with array of reference, we mean that the array elements are nothing but references to the actual objects. Initially they don't point to any object.

So, to access any property or method, you have to initialize each array elements to some instance, so as to avoid the `NPE`.

> what did my "new" keyword do, when I typed `View[][] allViews = new View[SIZE][SIZE];`?

It created an array of array, of type `View`. The dimension being `SIZE x SIZE`. But since `View` is not a primitive type, but a reference type. The values are by default `null`, as already explained.

> ```
> getLocationOnScreen(rPos[i][j]); // pass an array of two integers
> ```

Of course you passed an array of 2 integers. The component type of `rPos[i][j]` is an `int[]`. The default value is `null` for that too. But in this case, it wouldn't be `null`, as you have given the dimension for all of your inner array too.

If you change your array declaration to:

```
private int[][][] rPos = new int[SIZE][SIZE][];  // Missing last dimension
```

then the value of `rPos[i][j]` will be `null`.

Comment: Thanks! There was another question: `Can I start using the array right way, like the following line?`

Comment: @user1032613. Yes you can use it in this case. You have already given all the dimensions. So the inner array are also initialized.